# Android vs Desktop Application

Tags: android, jsoup

I'm not exactly sure how to describe the problem, but basically, I'm using JSoup to parse some html and pull out the article text. The method I'm using is:

```
    public static String getArticle(String articleLink) {
    Log.i("article link", articleLink);
    Document doc = null;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect(articleLink).timeout(10000).get(); 
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        return null;
    }
    Elements articleBody = doc.select("div.article-body");
    Element first = articleBody.first();
    return first.text();
}
```

When I pull out this snippet of code, and create a sample program in Netbeans, and pass in the link to the page, it returns the article just fine. But, when I run it on my android device, I get a null pointer at 'return first.text()'.

I'm not sure how this can be. The app is published and has been working, but all of a sudden, it started crashing, leading me to believe that something changed in the layout of the webpage, but I just ran the standalone program, passed in the same articleLink, and it works fine on my computer, but I get the nullPointer on the android. Same versions of jsoup too, any ideas?

Update: The value of the doc variable is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<title>Redirecting...</title> 
<meta http-equiv="refresh"     content="0;url=http://m.ncataggies.com/mobile/ViewArticle.dbml?    atclid=205823481&amp;DB_MENU_ID=&amp;SPSID=&amp;SPID=&amp;DB_OEM_ID=24500" /> 
<meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW" /> 
</head> 
<body>  
</body>
</html>
```

So something did change...

Comment: what's the page you're trying to scrape?

Comment: http://www.ncataggies.com//ViewArticle.dbml?DB_OEM_ID=24500&ATCLID=205821772

Comment: Line 68 that its referring to is "return first.text()"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server at `ncataggies.com` is checking the **user-agent header** from the request, and serving different pages to mobile browsers. Because you don't specify a user-agent, the server sees the default agent that Android supplies, which identifies it as a mobile browser.

In [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) you can set the user-agent like this:

```java
String ua = "Mozilla"; // I'd suggest using your current browser as reference    
doc = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent(ua).timeout(10000).get();
```

You can check your current user-agent [here](http://whatsmyuseragent.com/).